# undefined input from react form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in react. I created a form to get the name of the user but whenever I check it in console the input is always undefined.I dont know much react so any help would be appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      name:''
    }
  this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

  handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    console.log(this.name)
  
  }
  handleChange=(e)=>
  {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <form >
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} >add</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `this.state.name`, not `this.name`

Comment: Assign ```name="name"``` to your input.. Like ```<input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />```... Also change ```this.name``` to ```this.state.name``` inside the handleSubmit function.. Example:  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-forked-59n58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: ''
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state)

    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name='name' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.name} />
                <input type="text" name='email' onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} />
                <button type='submit'>add</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks, If you are new to React you can simplify this with React Hooks.  This is the way React seems to be going.  Have a great day. :-)

Comment: hey thanks man just wanted to ask that if I had to take multiple inputs then I just copy ```  (new input): e.target.value,```

Comment: No problem.  I adjusted the above snippet for multiple inputs.